# how to receive contents of txt file using netcat

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection, netcat

I've tried to use this to receive the contents (and echo it), but I get the error of file not found, could anyone help me? Thanks in advance

```
netcat -l 127.0.0.1 1234 < file.txt
```

**EDIT:**

I've got it in a wrong way, problem solved now!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you try to receive or do you try to send? If you try to receive, why do you use `file.txt` as the input of your `netcat` command?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Sorry, I misunderstood the difference between send and receive. I've already solved this problem now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output to stdout and to file.txt:

```
netcat -l 127.0.0.1 1234 | tee file.txt
```

Comment: Could I echo the result like this? `echo $(./netcat -l 127.0.0.1 9001)`

Comment: I've updated my answer.